# Unable to open the file because you don't have permission with physical iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, share-extension

I can't find a solution anymore. I just developed a Share Extension in an iOS application.

Unfortunately, I have a problem that I don't understand and that I can't solve. Indeed, during all the development time, I developed the application with the iPhone 14 Simulator under iOS 16. And, it worked perfectly.

But when I launch the application on a physical iPhone, I have an error that I never had with the Simulator:

> Error: Unable to open the file "1682093677644_IMG_1975.PNG" because
> you do not have permission to view it.

The urls look like this: `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/FFC8FD70-4DA2-4BB0-8030-C0695715BEF8/tmp/1682093755085_IMG_1975.PNG`

Of course, I tried to remove "private/" and to format the urls in all directions without success.

Extension code:

```swift
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    var files = [URL]()
    var data = [Data]()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // Request permission to access the user's photo library
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            if status == .authorized {
                // Get the item[s] we're handling from the extension context.
                guard let item = self.extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
                      let attachments = item.attachments
                else {
                    return
                }

                // Load the item[s] we're handling by looking at each NSItemProvider's registeredTypeIdentifiers.
                let group = DispatchGroup()
                for attachment in attachments {
                    group.enter()
                    if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                        attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil) { item, error in
                            defer {
                                group.leave()
                            }
                            if let error = error {
                                print("Error loading image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            } else if let url = item as? URL {
                                self.files.append(url)
                                if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                                    self.data.append(imageData)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeFileURL as String) {
                        attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeFileURL as String, options: nil) { item, error in
                            defer {
                                group.leave()
                            }
                            if let error = error {
                                print("Error loading file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            } else if let url = item as? URL {
                                self.files.append(url)
                                if let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                                    self.data.append(fileData)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        group.leave()
                    }
                }

                group.notify(queue: .main) {
                    // Copy files to temporary directory
                    let copiedFiles = self.copyFilesToTemporaryDirectory()
                    let filesString = copiedFiles.map { $0.absoluteString }.joined(separator: ",")
                    let urlString = "EvolisApp://?files=\(filesString)"

                    // Open the application with copied file URLs.
                    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
                        print("Failed to create URL from string: \(urlString)")
                        return
                    }
                    _ = self.openURL(url)

                    self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            } else {
                print("Access to photo library not granted.")
            }
        }
    }

    private func copyFilesToTemporaryDirectory() -> [URL] {
        var copiedFiles = [URL]()
        let tempDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)

        for file in files {
            let fileName = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))_\(file.lastPathComponent)"
            let tempFileURL = tempDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

            do {
                let fileType = file.pathExtension.lowercased()
                if fileType == "pdf" {
                    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: file)
                    if let pageCount = pdfDocument?.pageCount {
                        for pageIndex in 0..<pageCount {
                            let page = pdfDocument?.page(at: pageIndex)
                            let pageTempFileName = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))_\(file.lastPathComponent)_page\(pageIndex+1).pdf"
                            let pageTempFileURL = tempDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(pageTempFileName)
                            if let pageData = page?.dataRepresentation {
                                try pageData.write(to: pageTempFileURL)
                                copiedFiles.append(pageTempFileURL)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: file, to: tempFileURL)
                    copiedFiles.append(tempFileURL)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Failed to copy file to temporary directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        return copiedFiles
    }

    // Open the application with the file URLs
    // Don't use UIApplication
    @objc func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
            }

            responder = responder?.next
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

And the code of my host application (Main):

```swift
@main
struct EvolisAppApp: App {
    @State private var isSplashScreenDismissed = false
    @State private var printJobOption = PrintJobOption()
    @State private var sharedFiles: [URL] = []
    @State var isModalDisplayed = false
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                Color("Background")
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                if isSplashScreenDismissed {
                    ContentView()
                        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isModalDisplayed) {
                            PrinterSelectionModal(printJobOption: $printJobOption)
                        }
                        .onOpenURL { url in
                            if url.absoluteString.contains("EvolisApp") {
                                isModalDisplayed = true
                                
                                let formattedURL = formatURL(url: url)
                                let files = formattedURL.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: ",").compactMap { URL(string: $0) }
                                printJobOption.setUrls(urls: files)
                            }
                            
                        }
                } else {
                    LaunchScreen(isSplashScreenDismissed: $isSplashScreenDismissed)
                }
            }.onAppear {
                SettingsManager.shared.loadSettings()
            } //: ZStack
        } //: WindowGroup
    } //: Body
    
    func formatURL(url: URL) -> URL {
        let urlString = url.absoluteString
        let formattedString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "EvolisApp://?files=", with: "")
        let formattedURL = URL(string: formattedString)
        
        return formattedURL!
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso